# How can i use ecr with normal docker login from other registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab

I want to use normal `docker login` for normal stuff but for ecr i want to credHelpers as mentioned in tutorial

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers

But it look like it tell me to replace the whole file

~/.docker/config.json  with

```
{
"credHelpers": {
                "aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
        }

}
```

but my file already has this conetnt and i dont want to break stuff

```
{
        "auths": {
                "registry.gitlab.com": {
                        "auth": "fdfdfdfdfd"
                }
        }
}
```

can i do something like

```
{
        "auths": {
                "registry.gitlab.com": {
                        "auth": "fdfdfdfdfd"
                }
        },


"credHelpers": {
                "dfdfdfdfd.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
        }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen in [Configuration files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files), it is not the case: you can have both a credHelper and login information (not on the same domain)

So you can do what you want, possibly adding your credHelper information manually to the config file.

[Issue 41](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/issues/41#issuecomment-311253685) mentions:

> I've been able to get credsStore to work fine, with the addition of auths

```
{
  "auths" : {
    "registry.gitlab.com": { "auth": "fdfdfdfdfd" },
    "[aws_account_id].dkr.ecr.[region].amazonaws.com" : {}
  },
  "credsStore" : "ecr-login"
}
```

So you can list in `auths` URLs with credentials or with *no* credentials (empty `{}`). The latter will be managed by the credential helper (like [`awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper))

---

[imdibiji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812351/imdibiji) reports, [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932911/how-can-i-use-ecr-with-normal-docker-login-from-other-registry/49934085#comment97115315_49934085), having to use the following format for avoiding:

```
error: ERRO[0000] Error parsing the serverURL 
error="docker-credential-ecr-login can only be used with 
       Amazon Elastic Container Registry." 
serverURL="index.docker.io/v1"
```

The format:

```
{
  "auths": {
     "index.docker.io/v1": {"auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } }, 
   "credHelpers": { "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login" }
}
```

Comment: i tried that and it says no basic auth present . if i try  ecr login manually then it works but not with helper

Comment: @Mirage Check if the prerequisites listed in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper are matched in your case.

Comment: @Mirage what version of docker are you using?

Comment: @Mirage I have edited the answer with a working example.

Comment: I have a dockerhub auth and an ECR - pulling from ecr and dockerhub registry work, but when I used a dockerhub tag, I get this error: ERRO[0000] Error parsing the serverURL                   error="docker-credential-ecr-login can only be used with Amazon Elastic Container Registry." serverURL="https://index.docker.io/v1/" -- it still pulls the image, though.

Comment: @imdibiji Strange. If this is blocking, a new and separate question might be useful here.

Comment: @VonC - I found a format that avoids the error and allows me to pull from both private registries:  
`
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  },
  "credHelpers": {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
   }
}
` (sorry about formatting)

Comment: Thenk you for this feedback: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: It didn't work for me :( and gives the following error
`.docker/config.json: Invalid auth configuration file`

Comment: @MohamedSaleh That seems to point out an invalid JSON content in that file. Could you delete (or rename for safekeeping) said file, as in https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/401#issuecomment-477571869?

Comment: @VonC I have tried the deletion of file also didn't work for me
As I can see, I have installed docker-ecr-helper and configured it as per documentation, but it fails always

Comment: @MohamedSaleh OK, then this would be better addressed as a separate question, with more context in it.

Comment: @VonC it was my error, it worked but as I'm using `skaffold` to mak the push to ecr, it wasn't tagging the image with the `XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\service-name` so without such tagging docker assume that it will use `docker hub`  and not `aws ecr` ... Do you have any good solution for that?

Comment: @MohamedSaleh Well spotted! I don't have an immediate solution, but again, a separate question could help. In the meantime, check the prerequisites in this example using skaffold: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-microservices-deploy-options/blob/master/skaffold.md#install-ecr-credential-helper.

Answer (score 1):

I needed AWS ECR in parallel to Docker Hub because I use free Docker images as well as my own images that are in ECR. I had to write the configuration like this, otherwise I always got the message "docker-credential-ecr-login can only be used with Amazon Elastic Container Registry":

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
  },
  "credHelpers": {
    "<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
  }
}
```

This worked fine.

Comment: I'd rather update `ecr-login` manager with its [repo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper). As default `credStore` I'm using `wincred`, as I'm using Windows.